# Importing demo data in Multisite

Tags: php, multisite, import, fatal-error

I have a multi-purpose theme, which allow to download complete demo site content/wordpress. Normally (www.example.com) it's perfect and run all demo request, last time i install a new **wordpress multisite network** and enabled as **Network** **theme**.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home1/user/public_html/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions/importer/import.php on line 491
```

Line number 491 in import.php looks like this

```
                            if( $response['response']['code'] == 401 ){
```

Here is complete block of php code from line number 489 to 511

```
                    <?php 
                    if( $test_error ){  
                        if( $response['response']['code'] == 401 ){
                            // 401 Unauthorized | HTTP Basic Authentication

                            echo '<tr class="row-401">';

                                echo '<th scope="row">';
                                    echo '<label for="import">Login details</label>';
                                echo '</th>';

                                echo '<td>';
                                    echo '<p class="description">Looks like your server uses HTTP Basic Authentication, please enter your login details:</p>';
                                    echo '<label for="args_login">Login</label>';
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="args_login" />';
                                    echo '<label for="args_pass">Password</label>';
                                    echo '<input type="password" name="args_pass" />';
                                echo '</td>';

                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Here is details of wordpress network:
Subdomains not enabled,
Network Enables "beTheme",
everytimes asked from support, they refer to hosting administrator and hostgator support couldn't answer about MultiSite. btw I'm sure they are not blocking any request, as i mentioned this theme works fine with normal wordpress website.
I am confused what going on in Multisite Network or what should be exact solution for this?
My apologies if there is already this questions asked but i couldn't find anywhere question/answer.

Comment: someone mentioned on muffin group support, add `add_filter( 'http_api_transports', function() { return array( 'streams' ); });
` in last row of wp-config.php but didn't work for me. I got error in syntax

Answer (score 0):

This error means $response isn't returning the array you expect but a wordpress error object. Try

```
if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    echo $response->get_error_message();
}
```

and see what you get.

Comment: let me try this one.

Comment: I just update that snippet - didn't replace a couple of variables correctly

Comment: now "SSL connect error
Login details 
Looks like your server uses HTTP Basic Authentication, please enter your login details:" asking and when i click on import receive another error `functions/importer/import.php on line 133`

Comment: What's the error on that line?

Comment: complete block of next error, there are 4 blocks for importing, menu, options, widgets importing.etc `/** * Import | Menu - Locations * */
function import_menu_location( $file = 'menu.txt' ){
$file_path = LIBS_URI . '/importer/demo/'. $file;
$file_data  = $this->wp_remote_get_auth( $file_path );
$data = unserialize( base64_decode( $file_data['body']));
$menus   = wp_get_nav_menus();
foreach( $data as $key => $val ){
foreach( $menus as $menu ){
if( $val && $menu->slug == $val ){
$data[$key] = absint( $menu->term_id );
}
}
}
// print_r($data);
  set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $data );
 }`

Comment: line number 133 is `$data   = unserialize( base64_decode( $file_data['body']));`

Comment: if that's the output to the page it seems like either you've got an php closing tag ?> up before line 133> Possibly an broken comment tag as well. You're getting upparsed php out so it prints as text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37925/discussion-between-mian-shahzeb-and-dg4220).

Comment: This is getting a little more complex than I have time for right now . . . too many errors. Maybe open another question of someone else can pick it up since your initial question is answered. I'll be able to look again later.

Comment: sure, btw it's 50% complete this time

Comment: Great, good luck